# Web forms: data consistency when editing a user "points" field

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am building a booking system. I have a form where an admin can give points to a user. The user uses those points when booking a slot. **The issue**: when the admin opens the user edit form the "points" field will have an initial value of N, for example 1, meaning that that user has one point. If before the admin submits the form the user uses that point (by booking), the form that the admin is looking at will still show the 1 point, which is wrong, and by submitting the form the point will magically be given back to the user. What would be a solution? Lock the user from doing anything while it's in "edit" mode?

I'm using the MERN stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual system for this is to get the current point value for the user at the time you load the page.  Store that value separately from the editable field.  Then, when the code that processes the form goes to update the field, it first checks to see if the current value of the field is the same as it was at the time the form was first presented.  If so, no behind-the-scenes changes have been made and the edit can be applied without problem.

But, if the current point value is different than it was, then some behind-the-scene changes have occurred and you would typically abort the edit because it's based on out-of-date info.  The admin must then apply their desired change again - repeating the process.

It is also important to do these checks in a way that doesn't introduce its own race condition.  How exactly to implement that is database-specific.

Comment: What would be a meaningful error message for the admin in case the points changed? I'm using mongodb, so I'm not sure how I can handle a race condition.